# Creating a component that copies field values from another component

Tags: tridion

I am trying to create a Component1 in Tridion 2011 SP1. I also have Component2 which has already been created.

While creating a Component1 in Tridion, I have  two fields  for that Component, one is called 'SelectedType' which is a drop-down having values A,B,C which are options defined in the Schema. The other field called 'Name' which is also a drop-down, but its values should be retrieved from the second Component according to the value selected from 'SelectedType' field.

Component2 has the following fields named 'A', 'B','C'. Each field in Component2 is multivalued and is of type text.

So for example if I Select value 'A'  from 'SelectedType' drop-down filed then my 'Name' drop-down field should get populated with the values fetched from field 'A' of Component2.

This functionality should not be implemented by adding any Extensions to the Tridion UI, or using any .NET code.

This should be purely implemented using the available functionality in Tridion.

Is there any scope of implementing event Handlers/Listeners in Tridion which populates values to the next drop-down field when an event has occured for the value change in first drop-down field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not built-in functionality of Tridion, so you'll have to write some sort of extension. If you stick to the statement "without a GUI extension or .NET code" then the answer is a simple "no".

If you are willing to consider writing an extension AND you are on Tridion 2011 (or later), then you might be able to get this done using a Data Extender since the dependency you want is between two Components (and not fields within the same Component).

Comment: I'm using SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1. May I know more Info about this 'Data Extender'

Comment: And my another question is if there is a dependency between two fields within the same component then how can we handle the same.Thanks for sharing your info.

Comment: Let me Google that for you...
http://www.curlette.com/?p=548
http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2012/04/sdl-tridion-2011-data-extenders-real.html
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_E4EFBE6E5CA24C01B2531FB15AE95AE2

Answer (score 2):

This will not be possible without creating a GUI extension I'm afraid. This functionality is not currently out of the box with SDL Tridion 2011. This is why the GUI is extendable.

Comment: but the 'Name' field according to my requirement should not be a 'Rich text Field'.But I'm forced to make it as a RTF field for my extension to work if I include any extensions like 'Button' to my tridion UI.

Comment: My field is a 'sipmle' field not a RTF field. For this simple field how can I implement a GUI extension.

Comment: GUI Extensions in SDL Tridon 2011 can be used to perform almost any functionality you can imagine. Have a look at the http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/ for some examples.

Please also consider committing to our SDL Tridion proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 it will help us get a dedicated SDL Tridion site on Stack Exchange

Comment: I notice you used the Tridion2009 tag in this post - which version of Tridion are you using?